# Cantor Intersection theorem and its interpretation?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

In literature its said that if {$Q_1,Q_2,..$} form a countable nested sequence such that $Q_{n} >= Q_{n+1}$ and all $Q_i$ are closed and non-empty, then **intersection over i**- $Q_i$ is closed and non-empty. What I think of it is using the property that infinite intersection of closed set is closed and since $Q_i$ are nested non-empty sequence, there intersection is trivially non-empty. But the textbook uses a complicated approach for this simple fact. Am I interpreting the theorem wrong and if yes could anyone provide an example to break my reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with countably nested sequences of nonempty sets is that their intersection can indeed be empty. For instance, consider the intervals of the form $(0,\frac{1}{i}]$. All of these intervals are nonempty, but if we intersect them all for positive integers $i$, we get the empty set!

Comment: but (0,1/i] is not closed in real line?

Comment: Exactly, and so that's why the theorem holds. But this is to show you that just because we take the intersection of nonempty nested sets doesn't mean we will get a nonempty answer.